# Desynchronizing Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a recursive function being called before a .click handler (this checks to see if radio buttons are checked). It's preventing my .click from executing. And if I switch them, my recursive function doesn't execute. Is there some way to desynchronize the execution of Jquery script so i can check to see if my checkboxes are checked AND run my recursive function?

In general, is there a standard way of doing this? Right now I'm running all my code in the header of the document, should I split them up can load the scripts separately with the html-script tag?

Comment: It would help to see the specific code so we can propose a better way of doing what you are trying to do, rather than just giving general tips for a problem that is hard to visualise the way you have described it.

Comment: If your recursive function takes a long time to execute, I would strongly recommend using `setTimeout()` each time it calls itself, even if the delay is only a few milliseconds. Otherwise, there's a possibility you'll lock up the browser completely.

Comment: hey yea sorry, my code is really jumbled, that's why i didn't add a code example. the timeout thing worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to execute a function asynchronously. For example,

```
function delay() {
    alert('world');
}

setTimeout(delay, 100);

alert('hello');
```

The snippet above will alert the user "hello", and after 100ms, it will alert the user "world".